# Domain of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Let $N\sim\text{Po}(\lambda)$ and $X_1,\ldots,X_n,\ldots$ be independent random variables $\text{Ber}(p)$. Consider $S=X_1+\ldots+X_N$. I saw in class that $S\sim \text{Po}(\lambda p)$.

What I don't understand is in which proability space $(\Omega,P)$ we're working. I learned that, if you have a Poisson random variable $Y$, then $\Omega=\mathbb{N}$, $Y(\omega)=\omega$ and $P(\{\omega\})=e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{\omega}/\omega!$. In the case of $X_i\sim\text{Ber}(p)$, I suppose that $\Omega=\{0,1\}$, $X(\omega)=\omega$ and $P(\{1\})=1$.

Is it true that, when you have a discrete random variable, you define it as the identity?

Which is the domain of $S$? It doesn't make sense to write $S(\omega)=X_1(\omega)+\ldots+X_{N(\omega)}(\omega)$, because $X$ and $N$ have different domains.

As you can see, I'm completely confused.

Comment: Example: Take $\Omega=\mathbb R$ equipped with Borel $\sigma$-algebra and some probability measure. Now prescribe $B:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by $\omega\mapsto 1$ if $\omega>0$ and $\omega=0$ otherwise. Then $B$ has Bernouilli-distribution. Don't worry too much about probability spaces (though it is good to have some eagerness). They are very flexible.

Comment: Sorry, but in my former comment $\omega=0$ must be replaced by $\omega\mapsto0$. Actually $B$ is defined as a function that only takes values in $\{0,1\}$, but its domain is the uncountable $\mathbb R$ and not the set $\{0,1\}$ itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If suitable probability spaces $\langle\Omega_i,\mathcal A_i,P_i\rangle$ exist for independent random variables $Y_i:\Omega_i\to\mathbb R$ then we can always construct product space $\langle\Omega,\mathcal A,P\rangle$ with projections $\pi_i:\Omega\to\Omega_i$.

If we define $Z_i:=Y_i\circ\pi_i:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ then $Z_i$ has the same distribution as $Y_i$ and can take its place.

So we reach the same situation **plus** the fact that the rv's are all defined on the same probability space.

---

Also the distribution of a random variable will ask for *sufficient* conditions on the space, but these conditions are not *necessary* in e.g. the sense that $\Omega=\mathbb N$ is *needed* if we are dealing with Poisson distribution.

Comment: So the domain of $S$ is the product of the domains of $X=X_i$ and $Y$? Also, the random variables always map $\omega$ to $\omega$?

Comment: Starting with probability spaces for $X_1,X_2,\dots$ and $N$ you can indeed take the product of these spaces, in order to get rv's defined on the same space. On this space also $S=X_1+\cdots+X_N$ is properly defined. For a discrete random variable $D$ it is not necessary that it maps $\omega$ to $\omega$. It is only necessary that a countable set $N$ exists with $P(D\in N)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

*A* sufficient sample space for your experiment could be $\Omega = \Bbb N \times \{0,1\}^\infty$, the Cartesian product of the natural numbers and an indefinite series of Bernoulli outcomes.   It's not necessarily the only one that could describe the experiment, but is it a usefull one since you can clearly see how the random variables of interest would map from it.   (Another viable sample space would be $\{0\}\cup\Bbb R^+$, though this is *somewhat* less than obvious (it has to do with expressing the fraction part in base 2).)

Who really cares?  All we require is there is that there is *some* probability space that can be measured by the random variables such that their probability mass functions are as described.

---

Now, we require the random variable $N$ to map $\Omega\mapsto\Bbb N$ such that the probability measure gives the result: $$\mathsf P(N^{-1}\{n\})~=~\dfrac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda}}{n!}~\mathbf 1_{n\in\Bbb N}$$

Where $\forall n\in\Bbb N:N^{-1}\{n\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid N\{\omega\}=n\}$.

Although we more often write this as simply:$$\mathsf P(N=n)~=~\dfrac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda}}{n!}~\mathbf 1_{n\in\Bbb N}$$

---

Also, the series of random variables $(X_i)_{i\in\Bbb N^+}$ maps $\Omega\mapsto \{0,1\}$ and the (same) probability measure must be such that for all $i\in\Bbb N^+$ we have: $$\mathsf P(X_i^{-1}\{0\})~=~1-p~,~ \mathsf P(X_i^{-1}\{1\})=p$$

Aka:

$$\mathsf P(X_i=x) ~=~ p~\mathbf 1_{x=1}+(1-p)~\mathbf 1_{x=0}$$

---

Then we can define the random variable $S:\Omega\mapsto\Bbb N$ via $\forall \omega\in\Omega~:~S\{\omega\}=\sum_{i=1}^{N\{\omega\}} X_i\{\omega\}$

Which is usually abbreviated as $S=\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i$

And without reference to $\Omega$, whatever it may be, we can show that, due to mutual independence of $(N, X_1, X_2, ...)$, and the identicality of $(X_i)$:

$$\mathsf P(S=s) = \sum_{n=s}^\infty \mathsf P(N=n)\binom n s \mathsf P(X_i=1)^s \mathsf P(X_i=0)^{(n-s)}~\mathbf 1_{s\in \Bbb N}$$

Which simplifies to a *rather* familiar expression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you know in general that there exist $\Omega$ and $P$ such that there is a Poisson random variable and infinitely many independent Bernoulli random variables?